# CSS, How do I set the min-height/width to the screen height/width only on first page load?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, css, code-behind

Let me explain the question, Currently I have set for example:

```
#masterpage {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

now what I'd want this to do is this;

When the page is loaded, it sets it's min-height and min-width to the pixels that represent 100% (this means, the width will set itself to 1920 on hd screens, and something like 1280 on the older screens)

But on resizing, I don't want it to ever change again, I just want it to stay the original size, so that I can zoom in and scroll around the page.
This ofcourse doesn't mean that it will stay that way forever, when one refreshes the page it should just reset itself (or it might actually save this with cookies).

I've tried lots of things to achieve this, some javascript and some stuff in the code-behind but I don't seem to get the actual desired effect unfortunately.
Has anyone ever tackled this problem, or does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Grab the window width and height on the pageload event, store them in variables, and then set up a listener for window resize events. When triggered, set the min/max-width and min/max-height of the primary container's CSS to those variables.

Comment: When grabbing them in the pageload event, they're always like 680px widht, and 480px height

Answer (score 0):

JQuery: If you want to get the correct height, you should try the window.load event which fires after all images and objects have been loaded and the page has been rendered:

```
$(window).load(function() {
     var bodyHeight = $("body").height();
});
```

Comment: This is not firing for some apparant reason

Comment: Are you referencing jquery api anywhere?

Comment: I don't think so, unless that is standard with a VS2012 Project

Answer (score 0):

With just JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var masterPage = document.getElementById('masterpage');
  masterPage.style.width = window.innerWidth;
  masterPage.style.height = window.innerHeight;
};
```

Comment: Somehow my window.onload is just not doing anything

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use different units for height/width. Use the vm/vh or the vmim/vmax, instead of percentage. these units refer to percentage of the viewport, while the simple percentage define a relative dimensions to the parent element. (check relative lengths section on https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

So, try something like:

```
#masterpage {
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vm;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Good luck!